# Javascript optimization: traversing N objects, varying types

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, optimization, types

I'm writing a pure Javascript library to solve a particular problem. I'll be working with potentially large arrays of identical objects. I need to traverse each object to perform actions on the values. I also have to specifically target an older version of Firefox with Spidermonkey.

As a simplified overview of how I'm currently doing this:

```
//entry point
function doStuff(objArray){
    var funcTree = {};
    traverse(objArray[0], funcTree);
    var len = objArray.length;
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        funcTree(objArray[i], results);
    }
}

//For the sake of brevity, the traverse() function will traverse the object, 
//typecheck field values, and set the next function, ie, if it's an array, 
//it sets tree.next = procArray, or an object gets tree.funcList = [], and for 
//each field it pushes {next: procFunction, field: [field name]}. It recurses
//into arrays/objects to map them
function traverse(){}

function procObj(obj, tree, results){
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.fieldFunctions.length; i++){
        tree.fieldFunctions[i].next(obj[tree.fieldFunctions[i].field], tree.fieldFunctions[i].next);
    }
}

function procArray(arr, tree, results){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        tree.next.func(arr[i], tree.next, results);
    }
}

function procPrimitive(prim, tree, results){
    //Do stuff here, place in results, do not recurse or return
}
```

Like I said, that's a very simplified version (there are other things going on), but you get the idea. I'm testing this on an array of several thousand simple objects, although it could be much bigger. In Firefox 33, I'm getting 20-25ms. In the older version, 60-65ms. Given that this is a simple test and the data going in could be even larger and more complex, I'd like to crunch that down further, but I'm not sure how.

In profiling this, the bulk of the time is spent within the function tree. I've cut that down by splitting procPrimitive into separate methods for each type (string, boolean, number), but that results in a lot of duplicate code, and there's still a good chunk spent on procArray and procObj. I'm pretty sure that a good chunk has to do with the inability of the optimizer to know which method will be called next in the tree and which type will be passed, which is why breaking up the primitive methods helped (cut the time from ~120ms to ~60ms).

Newer Javascript engines seem to be able to handle this just fine, but not the older version of Firefox that I need to target. I've been playing around with ways of doing this, but I can't seem to break 60ms. I've tinkered with attempted hints (which I know do not officially exist), checked and implented various tips on optimization and some jsperf benches (even writing a few tests of my own for the older version), and tried a bit with closures (which I think may be the key, but I'm having a tough time correctly building the tree with them), but to no avail.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I suppose it could be as it's fairly specific to this code, but I can't imagine that others haven't run into very similar optimization problems that could be applicable here, too.

Comment: There's a huge number of unknowns here and from the small portion of the code you posted it is quite difficult to tell what is actually supposed to be happening. You define funcTree as an object, pass it into an unimplemented function with no signature and then use it as a function. Can you post actual code or at least a bit more information?

Comment: Sorry, left a few things out to keep it from getting too long. funcTree will be an object containing the next function/list of next functions. One of the procX functions below will be passed as the value for it. When processed, it will invoke that function, which will invoke the next/iterate over and invoke each from the list of next until it gets to a procPrimitive function, where it will do whatever it needs to and return. I suppose tree isn't the perfect descriptor. Chain might be better. The procObj and procArray functions are essentially the same as what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

SUCCESS! It turns out that closures were the answer! Instead of passing the declared procX() functions for the applicable type, I modified things so that the traverse() function would instead call functions like so:

```
function _getProcObj(fieldName, funcTree){
    return function(results, data){
        //Same code as _procObj() in here
    }
}

function _getProcPrimitive(fieldName, value){
    var type = typeof value;
    return function(results, data){
        //Do stuff here and utilize type if needed
    }
}
```

Now the old and new versions of Firefox are very nearly matched, with 33 coming in around 24ms avg and the old one doing around 28-32ms. My best guess is that instead of using a single function for each of the processed types (array, object, various primitives), it would return a new function for each node in the funcTree, which could be better optimized separately for the type passed to the outer function. Whatever the case, performance is happily improved as a result. I'd like to squeeze it down a bit more if I can, but at least it's acceptable as it is now.